# Bind TextBox.Text to DataSet.DataSetName

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, dataset

I am trying to bind a `TextBox`'s `Text` property to a `DataSet`'s `DataSetName` property.

I get

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column DataSetName on the DataSource.
>   Parameter name: dataMember'

If there a way to bind a single text box in this way? I think it has something to do with the fact that `DataSet` is a collection, so the `BindingSource` is expecting to have a table bound with it, not a text box.

Can I achieve this without creating a "container" class to hold my `DataSetName` property and a `DataSet`?

**Edit**

It was silly of me to not include any code. So here you go:

```
this.tableGroupBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(DataSet);
...
this.TableGroupNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.tableGroupBindingSource, "DataSetName", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
...
tableGroupBindingSource.DataSource =    node.TableGroup;
```

- `node.TableGroup` is correct (not null, points top the right `DataSet`)

Once the `TextBox` is actually painted, I get the above exception.

I am using Windows Forms with the designer, so the two first lines of code are automatically generated.

Comment: Can we see sample code?

Comment: can't you just bind the text to a property en set the value of your DataSetName in your VM?

Comment: This should be relatively straight forward: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.datasetname(v=vs.110).aspx. If you're having trouble with BindingSource, maybe you could try a DataTable? It's hard to know exactly what you're doing without code. Are you setting markup or code-behind?

Comment: @DanielLoudon Edited

Answer (score 0):

The `CurrencyManager` uses `ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(yourDataset)` to get its properties and since it doesn't return any property because of its type descriptor, then the data-binding fails.

You can expose `DataSet` properties in a different way by using a wrapper around data set, implementing a custom type descriptor to provide data set properties:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
public class CustomObjectWrapper : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public object WrappedObject { get; private set; }
    public CustomObjectWrapper(object o) : base()
    {
        WrappedObject = o ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[] { });
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(WrappedObject, true);
    }
    public override object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return WrappedObject;
    }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
var myDataSet = new DataSet("myDataSet");
var wrapper = new CustomObjectWrapper(myDataSet);
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", wrapper, "DataSetName", true, 
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```